# DataBind dropdownlist and the textbox inside the repeater from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox and a DropDownList inside a Repeater. And I want to populate values from the database in the TextBox and DropDownList. In PageLoad, I have `CategoryList.GetList` which is:

```
SELECT ID, Name, ActiveName, ActiveID 
FROM category
```

I have 10 values in that table and `CategoryList.GetList` returns a datatable with values something similar to below:

```
1, 'A', 'Active',   1
2, 'B', 'Active',   1
3, 'C', 'Inactive', 0 
4, 'D', 'Active',   1
```

Now I need to bind the values to the textbox and the DropDownList. Meaning 'A' needs to be in the TextBox and 'Active' in the DropDownList. And I want the DropDownList to have the values as only 'Active' or 'Inactive'. When I run the code below I see the DropDownList contains Active and Inactive multiple times. Can you please help me avoid that and have only unique values in the DropDownList? Thanks

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ca_temDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 35%; text-align: left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Width="230px" Text='<%#Eval("CategoryName")%>' />
                </td>
                <td style="width: 35%; text-align: left">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Active" runat="server" Width="80px" />
                </td>
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="IDHiddenField" />
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            rpt.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(ca_ItemDataBound);

            rpt.DataSource = CategoryList.GetList(1, 100); // Gets id, name, activeid and activename (activeid and active name are the text and value fields for dropdownlist )
            rpt.DataBind();
        }
    } 

    protected void Category_ItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ActiveDropDown");
            ddl.DataSource = CategoryList.GetList(1, 100); // Gets id, name, activeid and activename for the dropdownlist
            ddl.DataBind();     
        }
    }

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<Category> GetList(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = CategoryDB.GetData(pageIndex, pageSize);

        List<Category> list = new List<Category>();

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            list.Add(new Category(
            dataRow["categoryID"].ToString(),
            dataRow["categoryName"].ToString(),
            dataRow["activeID"].ToString(),
            dataRow["activeName"].ToString()));
        }

        return new ReadOnlyCollection<Category>(list);
    }
```

Comment: Show the code code of `CategoryList.GetList`.

Comment: Updated the question and the code to be more clear and also the question now shows what is returned from the datasource CategoryList.GetList. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want static items inside the `DropDownList`, you don't have to bind it. So change it to this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Active" runat="server" Width="80px">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Active" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Inactive" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In code behind change your `Category_ItemDataBound` method like this:

```
protected void Category_ItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Category ct = (Category)e.Item.DataItem;
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("Active");
        ddl.SelectedValue = ct.ActiveID.ToString(); // I don't know if this is the right property. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks king code, I updated my code like you suggested but get the below error "Unable to cast object of type 'Category' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'."

Comment: Ok then, cast it to Category and access its property.

Comment: This is my code for the GetList, updated it in the original question. I am returning a readOnlylist.

Comment: return new ReadOnlyCollection<Category>(list); Can you please show me how to cast it to this as I am a newbie

Comment: @Namekal I've updated my answer. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank you very much king code. It works but I had to add the belowstring c = ct.ActiveID.ToString();
 
                if (c == "True")
                {
                    ddl.SelectedValue = "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    ddl.SelectedValue = "0";
                }

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do it as my activeID returns a bool and I  have to check that with the if statement

Answer (score 0):

i think as i got your question:
ok i will explain using a sql query:

```
"SELECT id, name, activeid,activename FROM categorylist"
```

so insted of filling the dropdownlist with databind just add:

```
    foreach(var item in  CategoryList.GetList(1, 100))
    {
          dd1.Items.Add(new ListItem("text","Value");
    }
```

get the text and the value from the item.
Or you can use a dataset if you like.
if you want any help with the dataset just send me the database type.
hope it helped

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. I need the dropdownlist to have only 2 options active or inactive. And when the categorylist.Getlist returns it returns values A, Active ; B, Active; C, Inactive etc. A needs to show up in the textbox and active needs to be in the dropdown and so on. But with my code in the dropdown I see multiple actives and inactives as many records that are returned from the database